# Hibernate time zone. Where are the different values?

Tags: hibernate

All the examples for hibernate time zone are for utc. This is ridiculous, it's like one person wrote one article and everyone copied it. Is there a list of the different time zones available for nonstandard?

I'm using America /la for Javas time zone, so ideally a pst works

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it seems anyone can be a hibernate contributor.

So, basically, the brains that be decided that the should use the same timezones that java support - this isn't really documented anywhere, it's just How It Is.

The brave folk at Java just decided on some arbitrary strings and called it a day. You can find these strings - and thus the values that hibernate.time_zone will accept - in the ZoneId.class - java.time.ZoneId

So we have, in 2021:

```
    var0.put("ACT", "Australia/Darwin");
    var0.put("AET", "Australia/Sydney");
    var0.put("AGT", "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");
    var0.put("ART", "Africa/Cairo");
    var0.put("AST", "America/Anchorage");
    var0.put("BET", "America/Sao_Paulo");
    var0.put("BST", "Asia/Dhaka");
    var0.put("CAT", "Africa/Harare");
    var0.put("CNT", "America/St_Johns");
    var0.put("CST", "America/Chicago");
    var0.put("CTT", "Asia/Shanghai");
    var0.put("EAT", "Africa/Addis_Ababa");
    var0.put("ECT", "Europe/Paris");
    var0.put("IET", "America/Indiana/Indianapolis");
    var0.put("IST", "Asia/Kolkata");
    var0.put("JST", "Asia/Tokyo");
    var0.put("MIT", "Pacific/Apia");
    var0.put("NET", "Asia/Yerevan");
    var0.put("NST", "Pacific/Auckland");
    var0.put("PLT", "Asia/Karachi");
    var0.put("PNT", "America/Phoenix");
    var0.put("PRT", "America/Puerto_Rico");
    var0.put("PST", "America/Los_Angeles");
    var0.put("SST", "Pacific/Guadalcanal");
    var0.put("VST", "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh");
    var0.put("EST", "-05:00");
    var0.put("MST", "-07:00");
    var0.put("HST", "-10:00");
```

Which I guess means that you can also just put a string -03:00 or whatever for hibernate to use too.

Comment: FYI this is a global standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones